# How can I use different color schema between vim and gvim

Tags: vim, colors

What should I write in my `.vimrc` file to test whether I am running **vim** or **gvim**.

Because the colorscheme I like very much is beautiful in vim, but is ugly in gvim. So I want it that when I am in vim, I use this aforementioned colorscheme, and when I am in gvim, use another colorscheme.

Is there any vimscript code can implement this function?

Comment: Your googling will be greatly improved if you use the correct name: colorscheme.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These two pages have a lot of info on color schemes and how to switch them:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes
http://www.indelible.org/ink/vim-colorschemes/

It also features the issue you have:

```
if has('gui_running')
    " GUI colors
    colorscheme foo
else
    " Non-GUI (terminal) colors
    colorscheme bar
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

gvim has its own configuration file, `.gvimrc`. Settings that you put in this file will override `.vimrc` settings for gvim only.

Comment: I touch a .gvimrc file, and the gvim is the .gvimrc's color scheme, but when I select "Edit->Startup Settings", it opens the .vimrc file. and I set the font, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

from my experiences using the Settings sub menu in gVim does override the gvimrc.

If you want to set the font in gVim add these lines to your gvimrc

`set guifont=WhateverFontYouWant\ 011`

& substitute the size for the value you require